# Passing schema name as a parameter in spring jdbc template doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

Here is the code snippet that I am trying to execute.

```
String schema = _2022_12_003_data
final String s = "SELECT * FROM ?.network limit 1";
final List<Map<String, Object>> maps = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(s, schema);
```

I am trying to pass the schema name but it is giving me an exception
`Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 1, number of columns: 0.`

I tried passing schema name through `spring.datasource.url` and with `Connection.setSchema` but it doesn't seem to add schema name that way. I also tried passing the parameter as MapSqlParameterSource but I got another exception `Can't infer the SQL type to use for an instance of org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource`.

How to correctly get the schema name within the query?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is not possibile to use parameter-placeholders (`?` or `:<paramname>`) for any other than values- (insert/update) or where-expression in prepared statement. You need to set your configurable schema-name by yourself. But be careful and make sure, to don't open a door for sql-injections. Validate the name, before using it. The most simple name-validator would avoid whitespace and allows only characters, numbers and underscore. For a first start, you could validate with this regex: `^[a-zA-Z0-9_]+$`

DO NEVER USE UNCHECKED CODE, so don't trust me unchecked :-)